# Combining detail data with summed data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a sales performance analysis report for my company that takes two sets of sales targets.

1. Sales Targets for existing customers - identified with an account number with a target set for each customer, for each month. Each customer is assigned to a sales rep so we can calculate the existing sales target total for that rep easily. Stored in a table of its own.
2. Sales Targets for new business - This is a lump sum figure for each sales representative of how much new business they must win in this financial year. Stored in a table of its own with columns identify the month, year, rep and giving the amount.

My ETL script creates/updates a new table row for each customer for each month showing the sales, targets and variance against target for the customer.

The problem I am having is how to handle the new business as these figures are lump sum for the whole year. If I just link them up I'll end up with a target that is a multiple of the number of new customers and amounts when I sum it up rather than a true total.

Has anyone got a similar experience or project where this kind of aggregation has caused them issues?

So in my table `Sales_Targets` I have columns:

```
Company, Account Code, Target Type, Target, Cal Year, Cal Month, Month End
```

With data:

```
BWA  P001          Large        40000   2013      7          2013-07-31
```

In my `Other_Targets` table I have the same information minus the account code as the data has been generalized as we don't yet know which accounts will be new. The `target type` in the this table is set to "new".

Danny

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results to clarify your question?

Comment: Are you aggregating (grouping) by customer or sales rep?

Comment: On my existing sales data by customer by month. On my new business data I want to show sales by customer by but the target is assigned to the sales rep. I want it to be split down by the number of new customers they take on. This would then equal the total target assigned to the rep. Presumably I am taking the right sort of approach feel free to shoot me down if I'm way off here

Comment: A better technique of describing your issue is to provide sample data and expected results. This will increase and the possibility of help. Generally, in this format, your question is difficult for understanding.

Comment: Perhaps providing a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that shows your database schema along with some sample data would help us in solving your problem.  Also, what do you expect the results to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get the Accounts, with the actual and target for each. Then, you want to get two more numbers: 
1. The "other target" for that Sales rep
2. The total number of new businesses this sales rep got

In Sql Server, you could nest a Select sub-query inside the outer select clause. And you can nest another to count the number of new customers. Finally, you can divide these two, to get the average new-customer target for the sales rep assigned to the account.

It will look something like the query below, but [see this Fiddle for more detail](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1ab7/3) on the assumed structure.

```
select Account_Code, Cal_YYYYMM, Act_Sales, Sales_Rep
 , coalesce((select sum(Target) from Sales_targets ST 
    where ST.Account_Code=A.Account_Code 
      and ST.Cal_YYYYMM=A.Cal_YYYYMM
      and ST.Sales_Rep=A.Sales_Rep    
   ),0) SPECIFIC_TARGET

 , coalesce((select sum(Target) from Other_targets ST 
    where ST.Cal_YYYYMM=A.Cal_YYYYMM
      and ST.Sales_Rep=A.Sales_Rep    
   ),0) SALESMAN_OTHER_TARGET
 , coalesce((select count(*) from Actual_Sales A2 
    where A2.Cal_YYYYMM=A.Cal_YYYYMM
      and A2.Sales_Rep=A.Sales_Rep   
      and NOT EXISTS 
             (select 1 
              from Sales_Targets ST2
               where ST2.Account_Code=A2.Account_Code 
                 and ST2.Cal_YYYYMM=A2.Cal_YYYYMM
                 and ST2.Sales_Rep=A2.Sales_Rep  
              )
   ),0) SALESMAN_NEW_ACCOUNTS

 , coalesce((select sum(Target) from Other_targets ST 
    where ST.Cal_YYYYMM=A.Cal_YYYYMM
      and ST.Sales_Rep=A.Sales_Rep    
   ),0)
 / coalesce((select count(*) from Actual_Sales A2 
    where A2.Cal_YYYYMM=A.Cal_YYYYMM
      and A2.Sales_Rep=A.Sales_Rep   
      and NOT EXISTS 
             (select 1 
              from Sales_Targets ST2
               where ST2.Account_Code=A2.Account_Code 
                 and ST2.Cal_YYYYMM=A2.Cal_YYYYMM
                 and ST2.Sales_Rep=A2.Sales_Rep  
              )
   ),0) SALES_AVG

from Actual_Sales A
```

Comment: Perfect that's what I wanted just needed the steps. Up and running works like a charm.